# How to fully delete an entity model and connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity

MVC 3 web being built in VS2012 Update 1, connected to MySQL db.

I added an ado.net entity model as usual and all was fine until I realized the auto generated classes were not updating despite this bug supposedly being fixed in the VS Update 1.  Anyway, I ended up deleting all the entity files (.context.tt, .designer.cs, .tt & the ed,x.diagram) I also deleted the ' connection string from the webconfig.

I then started over, added a new ado.net entity model, etc, but it keeps trying to add a 1 to the end of the name (same as the last one), so i assume there is still some reference to the old entity model in there somewhere.

Where are all the references,s o I can delete them?  Is there a better way around this?  I guess I could just choose a completely different name for the entity model, but that seems cheesey.

Oh and one other thing, I grabbed EF 5.0 with nuget, but in the project references, and all through the web config, it is referencing ef 4.4.  Could this be part of the issue?

Comment: Normally, version 4.4 of EF will be referenced if you only have .NET 4 and not .NET 4.5.. check your project properties and see what version you are targetting

Comment: As for the connection string with a "1" on the end.. this may be a dumb question, but have you tried to find any references the old connection string by using "Find" and searching entire solution?

Comment: Matt - Thanks, I checked and I am using .net 4.0.  Do you know if it is possible to switch frameworks mid-coding?  And yes, I had done the 'find in files' thing, but I did it again and now all is good, so I must have missed something the first time through.  If you want to enter as an answer, I will mark it.

Comment: I have added it as an answer. Glad I could help.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, version 4.4 of EF will be referenced if you only have .NET 4 and not .NET 4.5.. check your project properties and see what version you are targeting

As for the connection string with a "1" on the end.. this may be a dumb question, but have you tried to find any references the old connection string by using "Find" and searching entire solution?